# how to split into character group?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split string

```
"abcdefgh"
```

to

```
"ab","cd","ef","gh"
```

using javascript split()

```
"abcdefgh".split(???)
```

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `split`, try `match`:

```
var text = "abcdefgh";
print(text.match(/../g));
```

prints:

```
ab,cd,ef,gh
```

as you can see on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/UtSIS).

Comment: @Prashant Bhate, you're welcome.